# How to specify partition key when using Azure Functions EventHub output binding?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

When using the [Azure Event Hubs output binding for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp), is it possible to specify a [partition key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.producer.sendeventoptions.partitionkey?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-eventhubs-producer-sendeventoptions-partitionkey)?

I have code similar to the below, but I don't see any way to specify a partition key prior to send.

Alternatively, is there any way I could use the Function parameters to bind an [EventHubProducerClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.producer.eventhubproducerclient?view=azure-dotnet), with an identity-based connection? This would be useful as the client allows for multiple ways to specify a partitionId.

I'm aware that it's possible to wire up dependency injection, and to use that to get the client, but I was curious if I could avoid that.

```cs
[FunctionName("EventHubOutput")]
[return: EventHub("outputEventHubMessage", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")]
public static string Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    return $"{DateTime.Now}";
}
```

Comment: I guess a valid question would be why would you want to specify the partition?

Comment: @MattDouhan "For example, you may want your back-end system to process an update command before a delete command. In this scenario, a client application sends events to a specific partition so that the ordering is preserved. When a consumer application consumes these events from the partition, they are read in order." [The Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-availability-and-consistency?tabs=dotnet#consistency)

Comment: It might be possible that there's some setting that could be manipulated at startup, but I haven't checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274359/offset-in-azure-eventhubtrigger-function-app

Comment: DO not think this can be done without DI since you cannot control many client options